# "Package not found: com.google.android.webview" RuntimeException when trying to login to Google Account

Tags: android, webview, google-play-services, android-tv

I am trying to install Google Play Services to my Xiaomi TV (Android 5.1.1, ABI armeabi-v7a) when this strange error appeared saying `com.google.android.webview` cannot be found.

I checked and the apk is installed in `/system/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk`.

What I have tried:
- Upgrade WebView to the latest version I found from apkmirror.
- Google Play Service of both variant 238 & 836. (explanations on variant numbers: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/#notes)

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15683): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15683): Process: com.google.android.gms.ui, PID: 15683
E/AndroidRuntime(15683): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.uiflows.minutemaid.MinuteMaidActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package not found: com.google.android.webview
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package not found: com.google.android.webview
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.webkit.WebViewDelegate.getPackageId(WebViewDelegate.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewDelegateFactory$ProxyDelegate.getPackageId(WebViewDelegateFactory.java:168)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.startChromiumLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:10511)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.ensureChromiumStartedLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:358)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.startYourEngines(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:472)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:162)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:558)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:476)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:463)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.google.android.chimera.WebView.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.login.CustomWebView.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.uiflows.addaccount.AbstractBrowserSignInFragment.onCreateView(:com.google.android.gms:59)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.google.android.chimera.FragmentProxy.onCreateView(:com.google.android.gms:373)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at fo.a(:com.google.android.gms:2074)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at gd.a(:com.google.android.gms:1104)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at gd.a(:com.google.android.gms:1286)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at fa.run(:com.google.android.gms:758)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at gd.i(:com.google.android.gms:1671)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at fy.b(:com.google.android.gms:388)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at ft.onStart(:com.google.android.gms:619)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at axn.superOnStart(:com.google.android.gms:2421)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.onStart(:com.google.android.gms:411)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at com.google.android.chimera.Activity.publicOnStart(:com.google.android.gms:416)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at axn.onStart(:com.google.android.gms:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6010)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
E/AndroidRuntime(15683):  ... 10 more
```

Can anyone enlighten me where I should start looking to fix this error?

For the record, this installation is completely feasible because I succeeded last year. But I was just keeping trying and didn't actually know what I did right. And later I screwed up and deleted the files I installed.

Comment: hey, did you found solution?